# python input EOFError after set io encoding as utf8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, eof

Python Version :3.5
OS Version: Windows7

After I set environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`, I can print some utf8 string (like love symbol \u2665, Korea words and Japanese words) as I expect.
(Before that i can only input Chinese word with gbk encoding but its totally worked fine.)
But now I can't use `input()` to get any non-alphanumeric character, it would raise a EOFError.

```
你好:♥・                                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                  
  File "codeTest2.py", line 9, in <module>                                          
    key = input('你好:')                                                            
')                                                                                  
EOFError
```

---

BTW:
when I use `print()` to print some utf8 string, (here are Chinese words, alphabet, Korea words, emoji characters and special character)

```
s2 = '송하나　♥　♥・'
print('作者id'+s2+'\n')
```

Terminal print:(a weird "inverted taper tower")

```
作者id송하나　♥　♥・                                                                
나　♥　♥・                                                                          
�　♥・                                                                              
�・
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of compiler and terminal are you using?

In Python 3.5 IDLE, this works fine:

```
key=input('输入:')
```

And in Python 2.7 IDLE, this works fine:

```
key=raw_input('输入:')
```

But in sublime Text 3, i should use this to declare using utf-8:

```
# coding=u8
```

So please give out your situation and code :)

Comment: I use VSCode integrated terminal and windows cmd.exe. IDLE do works fine, but I still want to know how to fix this problem.Thanks.

Comment: I have uesd cmd.exe by `python3 input_test.py`, and it works fine.What's your problem exactly? Have you use the `# coding=u8`?

Comment: there is no different after add `# coding=u8`. I only can say is I have changed python io encoding in enviroment variable.